# Best way to combine two-step service request screen and minimise cognitive load

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application, cognitive-load

I am currently working on a service aggregator app as part of a university project.

One of the main difficulties I am having at the moment is figuring out how to allow the user to carry out a search for particular service and receive the necessary feedback all on the same screen without pressing too many buttons?

I've come up with the following design below, which appears to be good for a first iteration, but how would I best combine both screens to have it so that when the user searches for a particular service e.g. "dentist", the "Please select a service type" suite of options appears.

It is rather challenging given the real estate of a mobile screen, and as this is a task that the user will be repeating it regularly, I want to also minimise cognitive load.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have them in an accordion stacked top of each other. at default the 1st form with the contents of your 1st screen would be in expanded state. after that is completely filled it would collapse and the 2nd form would expand. only after the compulsory fields have been completed that the book button will be enabled.
[image]